# how to store grid cell value in text box

Tags: asp.net

i m using the  statement below to store value of grid cell into a text box .
      But (GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text) is displaying as null .
   plz any one tell me why's this happening

```
Project_name.Text = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text;
```

Comment: more code...more details

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're GridView1.Rows[i].RowType is a DataControlRowType.DataRow